# Interpretation of nodes of infinite square well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

In the infinite square well, there is zero probability of finding a particle at nodes. What is the *meaning* of this result? Does the particle *teleport* in the regions between the nodes?

Or is it that this is a meaningless question in standard Copenhagen interpretation?

Based on the comments on this question, I believe that my point has not come across. Thus I'd like to refer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/619230/330899) question which has a very similar spirit to mine.

Comment: Consider that if you excite an acoustic mode in a chamber of air, a microphone at a node will pick up no sound. It's the same problem.

Comment: @JohnDoty if you are talking about the math behind the two situations, I agree. But here I am explicitly talking about the *behavior* of a particle. In your example, we can talk about the actual behavior of the air and deduce why there is no sound. I wanted a similar explanation for my case.

Comment: Wave functions behave a lot like air.

Comment: Consider how you excite a mode.

Comment: it is a *standing wave*

Comment: actually the probability is not just $\vert \psi(x)\vert^2$ rather $\vert\psi(x)\vert^2 dx$, and $\psi$ is not $0$ everywhere in the interval of size $dx$ near a node.

Comment: Repeating myself: $\vert \psi\vert^2$ is a probability *density*, so the probability $\vert\psi\vert^2 dx$ is not exactly $0$ near a node.  There is no such thing as “the probability at a point”.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Indeed. I am not debating or arguing over that. I am just saying that it does not answer my question. In particular, you can see that in my referred post the top answerer does the explicit calculation of what you are saying, but that was never the question. You might refer to the comments below that answer for more.

Comment: As you note, the question is meaningless, QM tells you nothing about what the particle is actually doing inside the well. You only get the relevant probabilities. You can ask about the probability of the particle getting from here to there (transition amplitude) but not how *physically* the particle travels or behaves over the interval of its transition.

Comment: well then I do not understand your question.  The probability density is just that: a density.  It does not describe the “motion” of anything as it is time-independent.  In a situation where a large number of identical systems are prepared, and the position is measured, there are some regions where the particle is seldom found.  There is no sense in which a particle “traverses a node” or teleports across one.  It’s a distribution of possible locations.

Comment: You seem to think that a quantum particle has a trajectory, and thus must pass through the nodes. It doesn’t have a trajectory.

Comment: @Ghoster You definitely can look at Bohmian trajectories. Only for this standing wave example everything will be stationary, but for the double slit experiment, to just pick another case,  the trajectories are here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory#Double-slit_experiment

Answer (score -1):

The best theory of matter that we have is quantum field theory (QFT). The Schrodinger equation used
in your example is just a simple approximation to QFT, it only describes "single-particle states" in
QFT. That's not enough to describe experiments that detect positions or other things, as those would certainly involve other particles.

Also, the meaning of "particle" has changed from the classical point particle idea to something
that is more like an abstract accounting
method for describing states in QFT (the number of particles is how many creation operators you
need to construct a state, each operator is usually defined in momentum space so you do not
get back anything like the old meaning of particle).

Nevertheless, there is a way of making the wave function describe a point particle: de Broglie–Bohm theory[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory)].
If you apply that with your standing wave solution as the pilot wave, you'll see that the Bohm particle is *standing still*
wherever it is positioned. A standing wave as a pilot wave describes a stationary particle. It does not go anywhere according to that description, so it also does
not need to cross any of the nodes and there is no problem.

Of course if you detect the particle (e.g. by shining photons on it), then your single-particle wave function solution is no longer valid (nor appropriate), and the nodes do not have
to remain where they were, so then also there is no problem.